# How run code when clicking on a looped button

Tags: php

I need to show a button for each value and do some function,
The following code is working for displaying the button only
but it doesn't show the result of the function after the button

```
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
foreach( $ids as $id ) {
    $post_url = get_the_permalink($id);
    echo $post_url."<input type='submit' name='doit' value='Change'><br>";

    $doit = $_POST['doit'];
    if(isset($_POST['doit'])){
        echo get_post_field( 'post_name', $id)."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: did you wrap all the code above inside a <form> tag with action="post" yet ?

Comment: What value has $_POST['doit'] when you print it?

Comment: Yes, I did @lamtacvu

Comment: Its a button, it should execute a function only, it doesn't has any values @matthijs knigge

Comment: if you echo data in your loop function, it will echo all data with $ids when you hit one of those submit buttons

Comment: it doesn't echo anything at all @lamtacvu

Comment: i know your code above is in wordpress then you should replace " echo get_post_field( 'post_name', $id)."<br>";" to "echo $id;" for testing purpose first.

Comment: I did that too but nothing printed or displayed

Comment: Can you add the results of $ids in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this solution?

I added an ID to the name field so when you click the button it runs only the if statement of this button.

Also make sure that the buttons are wrapped inside a form tag with a method attribute.

```
echo "<form method='post'>";
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
foreach( $ids as $id ) {
    $post_url = "test.com";
    echo "$post_url <input type='submit' name='doit_$id' value='Change'><br>";
    if(isset($_POST['doit_'. $id])){
        echo $id . "_RUNNING <br>";
    }
}
echo "</form>";
```

Also **$doit = $_POST['doit'];** prints a NOTICE in php when it is not defined, it is better to check if **$_POST['doit']** isset before assigning it to a variable.